# Split csv-line by Regular Expression

Tags: regex, csv

Can you help me with parse some csv-line using regexp?
For example: `1,"2,3","2,3,""4""",,5`

I need to get this array `['1' '2,3' '2,3,"4"' '' '5']`

I tried to write this regexp. But its only split my line by separator ','.

```
(?<=,|^)([^,]*)
```

I find this regexp, but its work incorrect with empty cell(,,)

```
(\s*'[^']+'|\s*[^,]+)(?=,|$)
```

Can you write me right regexp to parse any string?

Comment: Have you tried replacing [^,]+ with [^,]* ? This should match empty cells, as well. You should also mention the programming language you're using and post a small example in that programming language.

Comment: Matlab Language.  
regexp('"1",,4','(\s*"[^"]+"|\s*[^,]+)(?=,|$)','match','emptymatch')

Comment: if a replacing [^,]+ with [^,]* I will get ['"1"' '' '' '4' '']. Its incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex you are looking for:

```
(?<=^|,)(?:[^,"]+|")?(?=,|$)|(?<=^|,)".*?"(?=,|$)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

https://www.debuggex.com/r/KVwn6W1zKG4tTXSI

Comment: Why the eight case(`""`)?

Comment: @Taemyr I have simplified the regexp so the eight case is more obvious (look at the second branch on the picture).